# popup not handled correctly

Tags: jquery, popover

i m trying to make a popover for my project, it closes when i click else where in the document but the problem is that it also closes when i click on popover div. it should be closed when i click somewhere else in the document not on the div.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cuYBD/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.fx.speeds = {
        fast: 120           
    };
    $("#popup-img").click(function (e) {
        if ($(".popup").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".checkbox input").removeAttr("checked");
    $(".popup").slideDown("fast");
        }
        else {
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
        }
    e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").click(function(){
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the click happened within the popup

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.popup').length == 0) {
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vzX7B/)

Comment: @Riturajratan you need to click on the body... the body element is small... so the click event itself is not firing... the problem exists in the OPs code also

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).click(function(){
if (!$('.popup').is(e.target) && $('.popup').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
 }

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cuYBD/4/)

Comment: $(document).click(function(){ should be $(document).click(function(e){

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

my old fiddle didnt do the hole job, here is the new one that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/cuYBD/11/

In the fiddle i replaced the body with a div#mybody.

change your body.click Function to:

```
$("body").click(function(e){
    var bodyfound = false;
    $(e.target).parents().each(function() {
        if($(this).is(".popup")) {
            bodyfound=true;
           return;
    }
    });
    if(!bodyfound) {
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$("body").click(function(){
  $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
});

$(".popup").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```